# Docker-machine: Error with pre-create check in windows

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I've installed docker-machine version 0.14.0 on my windows 7. I am trying to create machines like a manager, workers when entering `docker-machine create --driver hyperv manager1` to create a manager getting the following error:

```
Error with pre-create check: "read tcp 127.0.0.1:50491->127.0.0.1:50490: wsarecv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."
```

Wrapper Docker Machine process exiting due to closed plugin server (connection is shut down)

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are trying to create a machine using `--driver hyperv` from windows 7 machine and this option is available for Windows 10/HyperV

[The documentation](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part4/) says you have to use `docker-machine create --driver virtualbox manager1` on Mac, Linux, Windows 7 & 8

Hope this will help you

Comment: I'm using Windows10 and I'm stuck with the same error.

Comment: For Windows 10 home also, you need to run the same command.